# How do I search OneNote page for hashtag+word? (#text)

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

Trying to use OneNote API to search a page for a word with hashtag (e.g. #taskclone).  This is producing an error from the API.

Link to Odata structure and syntax used by API - http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398071

I think the issue is related to the structure of the URL components in my query, which is why I added the second link.  Would love an example of a working query including "#word".

**UPDATE:**
Tried url encoding with /api/v1.0/me/notes/pages?search=%23taskclone, which caused no errors but gave a response back with no value:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/pages(parentSection(id,name,self))","value":[

  ]
}
```

Changing to/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages?search=taskclone works perfectly.

Here's the note text if it helps
 [OneNote Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytjGN.png)

Comment: Forgot to mention.  Search for text without the hashtag work fine

Comment: Do you need to escape or unescape the #?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are URL encoding the "search" query param:

This should work:
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages?search=%23target
This will not work:
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages?search=#target

What kind of error are you getting back? What response code/response content?

Comment: We tried URL encoding and the value returned is blank, but no error.  We used https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages?search=%23taskclone.  In the headers returned for this, the only difference to using "#taskclone" in the url was the **Content Length:** which I believe is the content length of the response.

Comment: Returned `{
  "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/pages(parentSection(id,name,self))","value":[
    
  ]
}
`  When using just "taskclone" everything works fine.  Same headers, but longer Content Length and full response.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current implementation OneNote Api should return same results for #taskclone and taskclone.
We acknowledge the bug that #taskclone is returning 0 results.
We are working on getting this bug fixed.

When the bug is fixed we will return same results for #taskclone and taskclone.